# Connection to database in Oracle Identity Management Installation

Tags: oracle11g, ldap, database-connection, identity-management

I am configuring LDAP using oracle identity management with MySQL as metadata DB. I am stuck at Database connection point.

[image]

Error says could not connect to database, I checked the credentials, it is right. Even checked to connect with command prompt using the credentials, it works. It may have problem of service name (third parameter of connection string) which we have specified as windows service name of MySQL - "MySQL55".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't install Oracle Internet Directory (OID) against a MySQL database. It only supports Oracle RDBMS as a backend. Among other reasons, the OID database schema contains PL/SQL, and MySQL does not support PL/SQL as a stored procedure language (it has its own stored procedure language with incompatible syntax).